# Ansible inside script command not found

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ansible, devops

Ansible:

```
-   name: Node package manager
    npm:
        name: pm2
        global: yes
    notify:
        - restart nginx

-   name: start the app
    script: ../files/common/pm2.sh app_name {{ user }}
    tags: test
```

Script file:

```
#!/bin/bash
APP_NAME=$1
USER=$2

if [ "$USER" != "" ]; then
    PATH="/home/$USER/"
else
    PATH="/var/www/"
fi

pm2 describe ${APP_NAME} > /dev/null       # line no 11
RUNNING=$?

if [ "${RUNNING}" -ne 0 ]; then
  cd ${PATH}${APP_NAME}/ && pm2 start npm --name "${APP_NAME}" -- start
else
  pm2 restart ${APP_NAME}
fi;
```

When I tried to run `pm2` command on the remote machine, It's working. But, not running from ansible script file.

Error:

> fatal: [webserver]: FAILED! => {"changed": true, "failed": true, "msg": "non-zero return code", "rc": 1, "stderr": "Shared connection to xx.xx.xx.xx closed.\r\n", "stdout": "/home/ronak/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1510939424.06-225768915266978/pm2.sh: line 11: pm2: command not found\r\n127\r\n", "stdout_lines": ["/home/ronak/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1510939424.06-225768915266978/pm2.sh: line 11: pm2: command not found", "127"]}

Comment: Please take a look: http://www.shellcheck.net/

Answer (score 1):

You're overwriting the `PATH` environment variable in your script.  This is used to determine where executables are located (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PATH_(variable)).

Short answer is to use a different name for `PATH` in your script and use absolute paths for commands in your script.